# Enable-Psremoting remotely

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

i want to enable powershell remoting on other computer remotely . And remote computer require authentication. I tried to create a batch file which schedules a task executing Enable-Psremoting , apparently i was unable to put it in remote computer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're in a domain, you can create a GPO to enable remoting. See http://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/

You can also [use `psexec` to remotely execute PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0800c68c-8cfb-4d6f-9c05-0e1a33412941/remotely-enable-psremoting) (see "whatyousay"'s answer at the bottom), passing in `enable-psremoting` as a script to execute.

```
psexec \\[computer name] -u [admin account name] -p [admin account password] -h -d powershell.exe "enable-psremoting -force"
```

If you're doing it for a large number of systems, GPO is probably best - although you could wrap a PowerShell script around the `psexec` version to loop through a list of computers.